# Fetch Odata using jquery mobile with phonegap

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, odata

I have developed an application where i can get data from server url http://user:password@xx.xx.x.xxx:xxxx/odata/OdataTMEDVDB/dbname?$format=JSON&$filter=YEAR%20eq%202015&$top=10&$callback=?

This query working fine on browsers, after compile using phonegap, the event does not fire at all to get data 
here is the code

```
var query = "http://user:password@xx.xx.x.xxx:xxxx/odata/OdataTMEDVDB/dbname?$format=JSON&$filter=YEAR%20eq%202015&$top=10&$callback=?"; //this is my callback

                 $.ajax({
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    url: query,
                    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
                    success: callback
                });

                function callback(result) {
                    alert("hello");
                    alert(result.d.results.length);
                    var shows = result.d;
                    $('#resultdata').html(shows);
                }
```

Please advice

Answer (score 1):

Some browser can refuse the URL basic auth password. Try to add your password directly into the header by using `beforeSend`:

```
$.ajax({
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   url: 'http://xx.xx.x.xxx:xxxx/odata/OdataTMEDVDB/dbname?$format=JSON&$filter=YEAR%20eq%202015&$top=10&$callback=?',
   jsonpCallback: 'callback',
   success: callback,
   //New code:
   beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic user:password");
   },
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Jan Hommes for your answer, actually the code running fine in all browsers, the problem start after converting the code into mobile application using phonegap.i have test your method ,works in browsers but not in mobile devise as app.

Comment: Do you use a base64 string as password?